# sequelize eager loading returns null for associated table record. Why?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, associations, eager-loading

I want to retrieve data from an associated table but the returned value is null.
This is the association

```
 static associate(models) { 
      appointment.hasOne(models.member, {
        foreignKey: "id",
        sourceKey: "member_id",
        constraints: false,
      });
      appointment.hasOne(models.system_data, {
        foreignKey: "id",
        sourceKey: "facility_id",
        constraints: false,
        as: "system_data",
      });
    }
```

Members association is returned correctly but when I try to get system_data I get null even if it is present in database.
Here I try to get:

```
 const getRelatedTableRecords = () =>
        include?.split(",").map((table) => {
          if (schemaName === "appointment" && table === "system_data") {
            
            return { model: db[table], as: "system_data", required: false };
          }
          return { model: db[table] };
        });
```

I don't understand why I can't get system_data. What might be the reasons?? Do you have any suggestions?

Member object

```
class Member extends Model {
     
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Member.hasMany(models.card, {
        foreignKey: "card_id",
        sourceKey: "card_id",
      });
      Member.hasMany(models.club, {
        foreignKey: "id",
        sourceKey: "club",
        constraints: false,
      });
      Member.hasMany(models.schedule, {
        foreignKey: "id",
        sourceKey: "schedule",
        constraints: false,
      });
      Member.hasMany(models.trainer, {
        foreignKey: "id",
        sourceKey: "trainer",
        constraints: false,
      });
      Member.hasMany(models.file, {
        foreignKey: "owner_id",
        sourceKey: "id",
        constraints: false,
      });
      Member.hasOne(models.facilities, {
        foreignKey: "id",
        sourceKey: "facility_id",
        constraints: false,
      });
    }
  }
  Member.init(
    {
      first_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      last_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      tc_no: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      card_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      registered: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      schedule: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "schedules",
          key: "id",
        },
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
      },
      club: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "clubs",
          key: "id",
        },
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        allowNull: true,
      },
      trainer: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "trainers",
          key: "id",
        },
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
      },
      birthplace: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      birthdate: { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: true },
      father_name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
      mother_name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
      gender: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
      profession: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
      address: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
      phone_number: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
      hes_code: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
      blood_type: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
      nationality: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
      profile_photo: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      file: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      session_ids: { type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING) },
      facility_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
      following: { type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER) },
      creator: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
      },
      updater: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "member",
      hooks: {
        afterCreate: (member, options) => {
          sequelize.models.card.create({
            card_id: member.card_id,
            credits: 0,
            creator: member.creator,
            updater: member.updater,
          });
        },
        beforeUpdate: (member, options) => {
          const changed = member.changed();
          if (changed?.includes("card")) {
            sequelize.models.member.update(
              { trainer: null },
              { where: { id: member.dataValues.id } }
            );
          }
          if (changed?.includes("trainer")) {
            sequelize.models.member.update(
              { club: null },
              { where: { id: member.dataValues.id } }
            );
          }
        },
      },
    }
  );
```

system_data obj

```
 class System_data extends Model {
    
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      System_data.hasOne(models.facilities, {
        foreignKey: "id",
        sourceKey: "facility_id",
        constraints: false,
      });
    }
  }
  System_data.init(
    {
      app_id: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      province: DataTypes.STRING,
      district: DataTypes.STRING,
      address: DataTypes.TEXT,
      phone: DataTypes.STRING,
      reset_credits: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false },
      asset_path: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      card_price: {
        type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0.0,
      },
      ticket_price: {
        type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0.0,
      },
      facility_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
      working_hours: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      capacity: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      season_based: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false },
      appointment_based: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false },
      seasons: {
        
        type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
      },
       
      season_capacity: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "system_data",
    }
  );
```

Comment: What field in `member` model points to `appointment`? The same question is for `system_data`

Comment: @Anatoly I updated my questions with the member and system_data models. Actually, I don't have any direct member/system_data field which points to an appointment. Members object returns anyway, but system_data does not. SO I am confused. How should this be written? What should I do? Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see `system_data` has `facility_id` as a foreign key to `appointment` so for `appointment` it should be like this:

```js
appointment.hasOne(models.system_data, {
        foreignKey: "facility_id",
        constraints: false,
        as: "system_data",
});
```

In both associations of the pair `hasOne/belongsTo` you should indicate the same `foreignKey` option with the same value that should point to a foreign key field on `N` side table in `1:N` relationship.
There is no need to indicate `sourceKey` as long as you use a primary key field of the `1` side table in `1:N` relationship.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but It didn't work. Maybe I need to add a belongsTo association in system_data. I'll try it

Comment: What exactly didn't work? No results? Incorrect results? Any errors?

Comment: I am getting system_data: null  in the appointments data, the association doesn't fetch the system_data. I don't get any error message

Comment: Can you show the generated SQL query along with parameter values?